# What is the function to get all items in ExtJs Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the form panel.

```
mypanel = Ext.create('Ext.fomr.Panel');
mypanel.add(Item1);
mypanel.add(Item2);
mypanel.add(Item3);
```

Now I want to get the list of items in mypanel so that I can add it to another panel.

How can i do that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`var all = mypanel.items.getRange();`

It will give you an array of all the child components.

Comment: what is the diff it i just return  `mypanel.items`

Comment: Once the instance of the container is created, `items` is an `Ext.util.MixedCollection` instance.